# How to update language without restarting the activity

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I have a dropdown, when user taps on it, i update the language from `English` to `French`.

This is my code.

```
    public void loadLanguage(String language){
        String languageToLoad  = language;
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.setLocale(locale);
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        recreate();

//        getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);

    }
```

The issue is that `reCreate()` method reloads the activity.  I want to know is there any possibility to update language without reloading the current activity.

Comment: No there is no possibility without recreating

Comment: The bigger question here is why would you add a functionality in your app that is already native to android?

Comment: @JoelLibby : I want to give user option to change language from, is there any way  possible to achieve this?

Comment: I'm afraid you have to recreate your activity to achieve that, unless you update all strings programatically for everything, which is not desirable and is a pain in the s for future changes.

Comment: Its possible as Elvision told. you need to update all strings